# What does `.[].foo[]` do in bash? Why does it match `..`?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

Look at the following:

```
$ echo .[].aliases[]
..
$ echo .[].foo[]
..
$ echo .[].[]
..
$ echo .[].xyz[]
..
$ echo .xyz[].xyz[]
.xyz[].xyz[]
$ echo .xyz[].[]
.xyz[].[]
```

Apparently this seems to be globbing something, but I don’t understand how the result comes together. From my understanding `[]` is an empty character class. It would be intuitive if

- it matched only the empty string; in this case, I’d expect bash to reproduce in its entirety since nothing matches it in this directory, but also match things like `..aliases` (in the first example),
- or nothing at all; in this case, I’d expect bash to reproduce the string in total, too.

This is with GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `[` starts a set. A set is terminated by `]`. But there is a way to have `]` as part of the set, and that is to specify the `]` as the first character. As an empty set doesn't make any sense, this is not ambiguous.

So your examples are basically all a dot followed by a set that contains a dot, therefore it matches two dots.

The later examples don't find any files and are therefore returned verbatim.

Answer (score 4):

Only **quoted** strings are **not** subject to globbing:

```
$ echo ".[].aliases[]"
.[].aliases[]
```

But un-quoted strings are subject to globbing. An unquoted string that contains an `*` or a `?` or (valid) `[]` (bracket expression) will be modified by the list of files that match it. In the same way as a `*` will transform into all the files in the matching directory and a `?` will match files of only one character, a (valid) `[]` will match files with the characters inside the brackets. A dot is a valid character:

```
$ echo a[.]b
a[.]b

$ touch "a.b"
$ echo a[.]b
a.b
```

To be able to match a `]` it should be the first character inside the brackets:

```
$ touch "a]b"
$ ls a[]]b
a]b
```

An empty bracket expression makes no sense (and is not expanded):

```
$ touch ab
$ ls a[]b
ls: cannot access 'a[]b': No such file or directory
```

That is why this works:

```
$ touch a]c abc afc azc a:c a?c aoc 
$ ls a[]bfz:?]c
abc  a:c  a?c  a]c  afc  azc
```

For `[` the idea is similar:

```
$ touch a[c
$ ls a[[]c
a[c
```

but it could be at any position in a bracket expression:

```
$ ls a[]bf[z:?]c
abc  a:c  a?c  a[c  a]c  afc  azc

$ ls a[]bfz:?[]c
abc  a:c  a?c  a[c  a]c  afc  azc
```

The string you posted `.[].foo[]` will match a dot followed by either a `]`, a `.`, a `f`, a `o` or a `[`. It is similar to:

```
$ echo a[].foo[]c
a[c a]c afc aoc
```

And it will match as follows:

```
$ touch .] .f .o .[ .a .b .z

$ echo .[].foo[]
.. .[ .] .f .o
```

Note that the directory entry `..` does not need to be created as it exists inside every directory by default. But a simple dot `.` won’t be matched by a glob as it needs to be matched explicitly (by actually using a dot).

But that will not match `..aliases` as the bracket expression will only match **one** character. To match several characters you need to use a `*` (anything):

```
$ touch ..a ..l ..i ..aliases ..alias ..ali
$ echo .[].aliases[]
.. .[ .] .a

$ echo .[].aliases[]*
.. .[ .] .a ..a ..ali ..alias ..aliases ..i ..l
```